# How to know if a button is enabled or disabled

Tags: c#

I have a 2 buttons Previous/Next changing their states if there are more rows to read or not.

So they are enabled/or disabled with conditions.

Is it possible to read their state?

On WFA

Here below how I check I look for a better way

```
        if (nextbutton.Enabled)
            NextBtnState = true;
        else
            NextBtnState = false;
        if (prevbutton.Enabled)
            PrevBtnState = true;
        else
            PrevBtnState = false;
```

Comment: button.enabled? it returns true or false

Comment: winform, asp.net, wpf, etc. Give us a bit more detail on how you are using c#.

Comment: @bto.rdz I know it return true or false I ask is possible to read as checkbox button.
Other wise I know to write if Enabled variable =true if not false.
What I ask if there is a another way to know it

Comment: What is "WFA"? What kind of app is this? Winforms? ASP.NET?

Comment: What you are doing is `NextBtnState = nextbutton.Enabled` and `PrevBtnState = prevbutton.Enabled`. That doesn't seem very useful at all to me. I also think your problem, if any, cannot be understood from what you posted.

Comment: Thank you all boys I got the answer here down

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if(buttonName.Enabled)// if button is enabled
{
//do this
}
else
{
//do that
}
```

As you updated your question, if you want it be more concise you can write,

```
nextbutton.Enabled ? (NextBtnState = true) : (NextBtnState = false);
```

Comment: That's what how I do. I saw there is no better way

Comment: @IsmailGunes What's the problem here.

Comment: I was just looking a better way that's all!

Comment: Thanks that's what I was looking, cause the previous solution is like my old style. And that makes only one line :)

Answer (score 0):

With the idea of @Pranit Kothari

the solution is

```
        NextBtnState = nextbutton.Enabled = nextbutton.Enabled ? (NextBtnState = true) : (NextBtnState = false);
        PrevBtnState = prevbutton.Enabled = prevbutton.Enabled ? (PrevBtnState = true) : (PrevBtnState = false);
```